# Magento Multiple Store Views - cannot get css and js files for new stores

Tags: php, magento

I'm setting up a few Magento stores that will work from the same back-end admin panel, but I'm having a problem with the index.php files for the new stores.

I'm altering the last line of code in the example below. It was originally 'Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);',which would get all the css and js files but would not display the correct store categories.

I then changed it to Mage::run('shoestore', 'website'); as it tells you to in [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/video-creating-multiple-online-storefronts-part1/) tutorial from the Magneto website. The correct categories are then displayed, however the css and js files are no longer working, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2008 Irubin Consulting Inc. DBA Varien (http://www.varien.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.2.0', '<')===true) {
    echo  '<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
<div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
<h3 style="margin:0; font-size:1.7em; font-weight:normal; text-transform:none; text-align:left; color:#2f2f2f;">
Whoops, it looks like you have an invalid PHP version.</h3></div><p>Magento supports PHP 5.2.0 or newer.
<a href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/install" target="">Find out</a> how to install</a>
 Magento using PHP-CGI as a work-around.</p></div>';
    exit;
}

/**
 * Error reporting
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

/**
 * Compilation includes configuration file
 */
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());

$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/includes/config.php';
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
    include $compilerConfig;
}


$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/../app/Mage.php';
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';

if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    if (is_dir('downloader')) {
        header("Location: downloader");
    } else {
        echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    }
    exit;
}

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}

require_once $mageFilename;

#Varien_Profiler::enable();

if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);

/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

if (file_exists($autoload = __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php')) {
    require_once $autoload;
}

/*
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
*/
Mage::run('shoestore', 'website');
```

Comment: Have you set the correct skin folder for each store view in the backend?

Comment: Hi Smiggle, I hadn't since that field was left unaltered in the video tutorial I linked to, however I added '../skin/' to the Base Skin URL at your suggestion and it's now working, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smiggle solved this for me in his comment; I hadn't specified the correct path to the Base Skin URL from the new stores index.php, go to System-Config-Your Store and then and then add '../skin/' to the Base Skin URL.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to System --> Configuration
2. Select store view, for which you are not getting css and js.
3. Click on "web"
4. Under unsecure and secure both:
   Change Base URL to new stores URL
   Do not change Base Link URL
   Change Base Skin URL to skin/
   Change Base Media URL to media/
   Change Base JavaScript URL to js/

**Note:**   Here  must be replaced by hardcoded url of your main store.

Comment: Hi Mohit, you actually anticipated a problem I encountered. I was getting 404 errors but changing the Base Link URL back to its original value fixed that, so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

also if you are using a theme, try SYSTEM > DESIGN > ADD DESIGN CHANGE and then select the theme for your new store